# NHibernate: retrieve current database server DateTime

Tags: nhibernate, datetime

How could I get the current DateTime from the database server, using NHibernate? 
I tried to use the current_date expression, but it doesn't seem to work outside the where clause. What I need is something like `SELECT getdate()`. This query in SQL server gets de current datetime from the server, I just don't know how to put it in HQL dialect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is just to use a named SQL query in your mapping file:

```
<sql-query name="CurrentDate">
  <![CDATA[
    select getdate()
  ]]>
</sql-query>
```

Then in your calling code:

```
IQuery q = session.GetNamedQuery("CurrentDate");
var date = q.UniqueResult<DateTime>();
```

Of course, this only works if you're looking to retrieve only the date and not the date plus other parts of your entities.

Comment: Right - this syntax would only work in SQL Server (and maybe Sybase).  This isn't a great solution if database portability is important.