# Get current database server date using Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532901/nhibernate-retrieve-current-database-server-datetime), but I don't know how to translate those solution (in NHibernate) to ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a named queries (which I'm not even sure if Castle supports) you could create a native query which is essentially the same thing IMO.

```
    public static DateTime FindServerDateTime()
    {
        return Helper.GetSession()
            .CreateSQLQuery("select getdate()")
            .UniqueResult<DateTime>();
    }
```

Replace `Helper.GetSession()` with whatever function or property you use to fetch the Castle AR session.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, Castle ActiveRecord does support HQL and SQL named queries (with `[HqlNamedQuery]` and `[SqlNamedQuery]` respectively), see [this article](http://www.kenegozi.com/blog/2008/05/09/using-nhibernates-named-queries-with-activerecord.aspx). For this particular case, I agree with Mike, just use a simple SQL query.